# NGINX + Kubernetes Ingress + Google Cloud Load Balancing

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently trying to configure a Kubernetes environment.

Currently I have a Docker image which serves my compiled Angular application via Nginx.

The `default.conf` of the Nginx is:

```
server {
  listen 80;

   location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Ingress configuration (mapped to Google Cloud Load Balancer since I'm using Kubernetes Cluster)

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: fullstack-ingress
   annotations:
     ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
 spec:
   rules:
   - http:
       paths:
       - path: /app
         backend:
           serviceName: frontend-main
           servicePort: 80
       - path: /app/*
         backend:
           serviceName: frontend-main
           servicePort: 80
       - path: /core
         backend:
           serviceName: backend-core
           servicePort: 80
```

Whenever I request my front-end using `http://[loadbalancerip]/app/`, all request sent to my angular docker are `GET /app/inline.js` when they should be `GET /inline.js` in order to work.

I tried directly in my cluster with `curl` and the file works. I only need to get rid of the "/app". How can I do that? Is that in the Nginx configuration or in the Ingress file?

I would rather fix it in the Ingress file, since I will probably have the same issue when I will be deploying my back-end which are .NET Core and Kestrel.

Comment: You may check this: https://m1r.site/2ByDEwc

Comment: Could You show your service please?

Comment: I just setuped a nginx-ingress and it works properly, as this ingress does not ignore the "rewrite-target: /". Request are properly routed to my backend service. Any idea how to achieve that using GCE ingress?

Comment: Hi, can you please explain more clearly what are you trying to achieve? Do
you want to access the webpage with: `http://[loadbalancerip]` or access with `http://[loadbalancerip]/app/` and to have translated the request to the server to `/`?

Comment: If you configure nginx controller, you do not define nginx configuration manually. Since nginx default configuration is a file `nginx.conf` I am not sure how your `default.conf`is picked up by nginx. I would suggest to look into [ingress deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md) to see how it can be deployed safely.